# Activity not attached to windows manager

Tags: java, android

I have a floating widget (that draws over all the apps) that on a long click will show a relative layout (`remove_relativelayout`) from the bottom of the screen that shows an x icon so that the user can drag the widget to remove it.

On most Samsung phones I get this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.RelativeLayout{762db5 G.E...... ......ID 0,0-160,160 #7f09022d app:id/remove_relativelayout} not attached to window manager
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:569)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:463)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:101)
       at com.xxxx.dev.floatingwidget.services.FloatingWidgetServices.lambda$widgetLongClick$0(FloatingWidgetServices.java:20)
       at com.xxxxx.dev.floatingwidget.services.FloatingWidgetServices.lambda$widgetLongClick$0$FloatingWidgetServices(FloatingWidgetServices.java)
       at com.xxxxxx.dev.floatingwidget.services.-$$Lambda$FloatingWidgetServices$DhV3rKQxnQ9oEEnb70PNAJKR8NQ.onAnimationUpdate(-.java:4)
       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue(ValueAnimator.java:1558)
       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1349)
       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1481)
       at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
       at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
       at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:994)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7857)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Here is on start:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams paramRemove = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                windowType,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        paramRemove.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        removeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        removeImg = removeView.findViewById(R.id.remove_img);

        windowManager.addView(removeView, paramRemove);
```

This is the "onLongClick" function I'm using:

```
private void widgetLongClick() {
        GlobalFunctions.printLn(">>>>>>>>>>>>Into FloatingWidgetService.chathead_longclick() ");

        WindowManager.LayoutParams param_remove = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeView.getLayoutParams();
        int x_cord_remove = (szWindow.x - removeView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y_cord_remove = szWindow.y - (removeView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight());

        param_remove.x = x_cord_remove;
        param_remove.y = y_cord_remove;

        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(szWindow.y, y_cord_remove);
        int mDuration = 100;
        if(removeView.isAttachedToWindow()){
            if(param_remove != null){
                if(windowManager !=null){
                    va.setDuration(mDuration);
                    va.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                        param_remove.y = Math.round((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(removeView, param_remove);
                    });
                    va.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding this RelativeLayout programmatically?

Comment: yes, im adding it to the windows manger, i editetd the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for my problem,
the problem was that I'm closing the activity before the view is loaded,
so what I did is to wait for 1 sec before closing the activity,
using simply:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //close the activity after 1 sec 
    }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you add this removable layout into your XML file and have it be `View.GONE` until you require it, this way you don't have to be worried about adding it programmatically and settings the correct layout parameters (this is probably what's failing in your current code).

Once you receive the longClick on the other View, you can toggle the removable layout to be `View.VISIBLE` and perhaps even add combine that with a quick animation to make it seem more 'friendly' to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cant add my remove layout to the same xml of the widget, it need to be from out side my widget layout so when i drag or press for 6 sec the remove layout will show from the bottom of the screen.